# Althought ANOVA is used to compare models that use continuous variables, can it also be used to compare logistic models created by glm()?

Tags: r, logistic, anova

I just want to see which of my logistic models fits the data better; can this be done correctly with the `anova` (and `chisq`) function?

Comment: Have you read `help("anova.glm")`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the models are nested. One way of comparing the models is using a [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test), and way of doing this is to find 2* the difference of the likelihood (see [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-are-the-likelihood-ratio-wald-and-lagrange-multiplier-score-tests-different-andor-similar/)) :

$LR = -2 ln\left(\frac{L(m_1)}{L(m_2)}\right) = 2(loglik(m_2)-loglik(m_1))$

The `anova()` function with test="chisq", performs this, for example:

```
fit1 = glm(am ~ hp + mpg,data=mtcars,family="binomial")
fit0 = glm(am ~ hp,data=mtcars,family="binomial")

anova(fit0,fit1,test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: am ~ hp
Model 2: am ~ hp + mpg
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1        30     41.228                          
2        29     19.233  1   21.995 2.734e-06 ***
```

Compare with :

```
2*(logLik(fit1) - logLik(fit0))
'log Lik.' 21.99501 (df=3)
```

If the null hypothesis is true, this deviance value or -2 * (delta log likelihood) approaches a χ² distribution. So we can test it is a chi-sq, as is done with the `anova()` function.